# Return strings containing special character

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find strings that contain the solar symbol (☼).
I looked up its ascii value and tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB].dbo.[Word]
 where Orthography like '%'+char(164)+'%'
```

It is not returning anything.. What am I doing wrong?

Example Orthography: 
愛☼是☼唯一

Comment: Your query is [working for me in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4cb32bdb88a41f95321c48663e18dac).  Not sure what is happening with your SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally include `WHERE` clause for such situation :

```
where cast(Orthography as varchar(max)) <> Orthography
```

If you want to find the string which has contains `solar symbol (☼)` then you can do :

```
where Orthography like N'%☼%'
```

However, this might be need `collation` conversations.